# Test Codeception/webdriver And Dynamic Form ID

Tags: xpath, webdriver, codeception, dynamicform

Just a question, i try  to perform acceptance test (fill a field) on form with an ID generated dynamically on every refresh. I am looking for a method to grab the form id, or to use partial xpath, i didnt find it.

```
<input type="text"     name="searchform_fb1831c63342af1bc6b8744181e2cc5b[simpleCriteria][NAME]"     id="searchform_fb1831c63342af1bc6b8744181e2cc5b-simpleCriteria-NAME" value=""     size="40" class="manage_ul_error text-input">
```

Any suggestion will be welcome thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to check `id` attribute for containing `searchform_`:

```
//input[@type='text' and contains(@id, 'searchform_')]
```

or, for starting with:

```
//input[@type='text' and starts-with(@id, 'searchform_')]
```

You may also check for `class` additionally:

```
//input[@type='text' and @class='manage_ul_error text-input' and starts-with(@id, 'searchform_')]
```